# How do I change number format to "General" for all cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a macro that apply `NumberFormat = "General"` to all cells in a spreadsheet.

This is what I have

```
Sub set_general_format()
    Select Case _
        MsgBox("Do you want to apply generic to all cells?" _
        & "Save before?", vbYesNoCancel, _
        "Or just change to numeric?")
        Case Is = vbYes
            ThisWorkbook.Save
        Case Is = vbCancel
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    Sheets(1).Select
    
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Select
        Cells.Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Can someone help me to improve this code?

Comment: Isn't it working? try:
ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"

Comment: instead of "Selection.NumberFormat = "General""
and remove "Cells.Select"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all of:

```
Sheets(1).Select
    
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Select
        Cells.Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
```

With:

```
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the three lines:

```
Sheets(i).Select
Cells.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
```

in one line as follows:

```
Sheets(i).Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
```